# Check whether GRANT EXECUTE TO user or role was applied

Tags: sql-server, permissions, audit

In Microsoft SQL Server, I can use

```
GRANT EXECUTE TO <principal>
```

to grant execute permission to some user or role. I'm interested in detection:

**How can I equally simply check whether that `GRANT EXECUTE` command was *already* applied to given user/role?** (by me or by some other administrator)

Example:

If I use `GRANT EXECUTE TO user01` and return back after few weeks: is there a simple way to check whether I (or someone else) already used `GRANT EXECUTE TO user01`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found where it is stored, so until someone posts simpler answer, I'll keep this code snippet at hand for case of checking:

```sql
DECLARE @username nvarchar(128) = 'user01';

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.database_permissions 
    WHERE grantee_principal_id = (SELECT UID FROM sysusers WHERE name = @username) 
        AND class_desc = 'DATABASE'
        AND type='EX' 
        AND permission_name='EXECUTE' 
        AND state = 'G';
```

Result `0` means negative answer, `1` means positive.